# font-family: inherit not working for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have css class and I have used an attribute:

```
font-family: inherit;
```

but it is not working for IE. It's working fine for mozilla.
Can anyone suggest me an workaround?

Comment: In which version of IE are you testing? Is your page using quirks mode?

Comment: The browser mode and document mode was different. its working fine now in IE8 and IE9.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 and before don't support `:inherit`, or are we talking 8+_

Comment: @user1538100, the workaround is to set the property to the specific value that should be inherited. Whether this is feasible depends on the context.

Comment: Looks like you opened a new question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650217/is-there-a-workaround-for-font-family-inherit-for-ie7

Answer (score 1):

font-family: inherit; support>= IE 8

> **Note:** The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit". (from w3school)