# Is there a workaround for font-family: inherit for IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

i have a css class:

text_css

in which i want to apply the inherit property.this is working fine for IE8 and IE9. i know inherit dont work for IE7.

can anyone suggest any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to set the property to the specific value that should be inherited. Whether this is feasible depends on the context.

For example, if you would like to have `input` elements have the same font family as the surrounding content, you can use `input { font-family: inherit; }`, though this does not work on IE7 (big issue?). But mostly people want to set the overall font family anyway, so you could simply set e.g. `body, input { font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; }`.

To get better suggestions, please specify the context and the purpose of using `inherit`. It is a rarely needed value.

Comment: i am using the inherit property in RTE(Rich Text Editor).

Comment: @ Jukka: The problem is that when i do some operations in the RTE input field, i.e. change the font-type or change font-size, or apply background color to text entered and save it, then the font-type gets changed. if i use font-family: inherit; it works for IE8 and IE9. but IE7 fails and shows the changed font-type after save action.